# file transfer Extra attachmate appends username to host file name

Tags: mainframe, attachmate-extra

Hi when I try to download a file from mainframe, using attachmate extra it appends the username also along with it. I dont know where to turn it off.

like for example - file name is   yyyy.file.name, then when i try to transfer of file it transfers username.yyyy.file.name.

in 3.4 the option to append user name is turned off. Still its happening

Comment: I think you will find the file name on the Mainframe is username.yyyy.file.name. Some of the ISPF utilities do not display your user name at the start of the filename, they figure you already know it. ISPF 3.4 is running on the Mainframe, attachmate is running on your PC and knows nothing about the options set on the Mainframe

Comment: On the mainframe the first part of the name (first HLQ), MUST be set up by the System-Programmers. Each user get his own HLQ and there will be other HLQ's like PROD or TEST. but you can not create a file ABC.WHATEVER where is ABC is any arbitary name

Comment: Hi whatever file name i am trying to transfer using extra, is not created by me. its a common hlq for the development team created by admin. with my id i can create and access those hlq's as well as hlq with my id i can edit/create/delete. what i am wondering is when i try to transfer file extra ? or option tso 6? is appending my hlq's to those file name.

Comment: Appending means adding to the end. As @BruceMartin has said, although you can often reference a dataset in ISPF without the user-prefix, it is actually there all the time. Paste an example of the screen you are using for the transfer into your question, using the edit link beneath the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose the entire dataset name (including the high-level qualifier) in single quotes.  This is a TSO (not JCL) convention - if you refer to a dataset without single quotes, it pre-pends your user ID as the high-level qualifier; however if you place single quotes around the dataset name it will take it 'as is' (well, it will uppercase it, since all z/OS dataset names are uppercase, but otherwise it will be 'as is').